# Can't modify document settings on LyX

Tags: lyx

I'm running `Lyx 2.0.7dev` on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I modified a document's language, but the "ok" and "apply" buttons are disabled... why? I already checked the file's permissions and they're "read & write".

Any ideas?

[image: LyX screenshot]

Comment: Perhaps you're missing the Ubuntu package for your specific language? (e.g. `texlive-lang-portuguese`)

Comment: this is a long shot, but is it possible you toggled read-only (`buffer-toggle-read-only`)? Are you able to change other document settings? What if you change the language *and* something else (e.g. LyX did not realize you changed something so it did not enable OK but maybe now it will)?

Comment: This seems to be an installation-specific and difficult to reproduce bug in LyX. Please provide further feedback to the LyX developers on [this bug report](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/8870). Moreover, please report if you can reproduce the issue using 2.1dev or 2.1beta1. You can install these on Ubuntu from the [development PPA](https://launchpad.net/~lyx-devel/+archive/daily).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue. Probably you have set "Listings" parameter to something that does not bypass validation and checked the "Bypass validation" checkbox. You have to re-check that box every time you want to save changes.

Answer (score 0):

In Documents >Settings >Listings check if there is a parameter set, e. g. "basicstyle"
If so, delete it.
Alternatively, you leave it there and tick Bypass validation.
I faced the same problem before - good luck!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!